# Using PHP to return results from HTML page

Tags: php, html

If I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/link1/">link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/link2/">link 2</a>
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

How can I use PHP to return an array containing the contents of all the href's?

ex:

```
$array[0]="/link1/";
$array[1]="/link2/";
```

and so on.

Comment: lalalalalalaa..... what have you tried

Comment: @Robin this code is not mine, it's from a friend, I have told him you can't use PHP to access content on an already served page rendered by the browser, and should use Javascript or jQuery instead, but I wanted to confirm with the pros if I'm right or wrong.

Comment: [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) are your friends here. ADD: Ah, "rendered by the browser" is a *very important* bit here...

Comment: Where is this HTML code coming from?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'd say "from a friend's IM message", but I get the feeling this is not exactly what you asked.

Comment: How does the html appear in the browser, are you putting it there using something like php or does it come from for example a facebook or twitter widget that you have no control over?

Comment: @ruda.almeida: Yeah, that's not what I meant.  I meant does the PHP have access to this file?  You said in an above comment that this is on an `already served page`.  So I meant is this in an HTML or PHP file that you have, or is it generated by JS?  If you want PHP to parse it, you're gonna have to get it there.  It'd probably be easier to have JavaScript get you the links.

Comment: To be honest, "not generated by PHP and rendered by the browser" was just my guess, I will need to ask more clarification from my friend -- Incidentally, @Salman's answer gives a really interesting approach that I hadn't thought of (for lack of knowledge, surely), and can be applied to HTML files even outside of the current server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) along with [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) (plus [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx) or [this chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)) to extract just about anything from the HTML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<ul>
  <li><a href="/link1/">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2/">link 2</a></li>
</ul>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$links = array();
foreach($xpath->query("//ul//a[@href]") as $a) {
    $links[] = $a->getAttribute("href");
}
var_dump($links);

// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(7) "/link1/"
//   [1]=>
//   string(7) "/link2/"
// }
```

Change `loadHTML($string)` to `loadHTMLFile($path_or_url)` to load contents from a file.